# ¿Como modificar un datalist?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Saludos tengo un detalle con un datalist, y quisiera saber si es posible hacerle algunas modificaciones.

Quisiera saber si puedo ponerle un minimo de caracteres para que se "ejecute", me explico.

Al escribir 3 caracteres, el input se mantendrá como input, y al cuarto caracter es cuando se cambiará a un input con un datalist cargado.

Lo único que tengo hasta ahorita es el datalist y la forma en la que se me ocurre es con javascript pero no sé si hay una forma mas fácil como un min o un max de elementos.

```
<datalist id="colores">
 <option value="Rojo"></option>
 <option value="Verde"></option>
 <option value="Amarillo"></option>
</datalist>

<input list="colores" name="colores" id="colores" type="text">
```

Comment: Tendrías que usar Javascript, la etiqueta `<datalist>` solamente atiende a los atributos globales que tienen todas las etiquetas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Comment: Agrega la forma que se te ocurre con JS editando tu pregunta e índicanos si tienes algún inconveniente